# Как преобразовать массив байтов в двоичный код?

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] ip = new byte[]{(byte) 192, (byte) 168, 1, 2};
        byte[] mask = new byte[]{(byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 254, 0};
        byte[] netAddress = getNetAddress(ip, mask);
        print(ip);          
        print(mask);        
        print(netAddress);  
    }

    public static byte[] getNetAddress(byte[] ip, byte[] mask) {
        return new byte[4];
    }

    public static void print(byte[] bytes) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Вам прям нолики и единицы вывести?

Comment: А чего не хватает для самостоятельного решения?

Comment: rjhdby - ага, нолики и единицы)

Comment: 0xdb - нашел вот такое решение:
String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(" ", "0"); только не могу полностью разобраться что к чему. Если можете - объясните, пожалуйста, прям по "буква")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы проще было понять происходящее, надо разбить длинную строку

```
String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(" ", "0");
```

на отдельные операции. Прежде всего выясним для чего нужно `b & 0xFF`.

В Java переменная типа byte в старшем разряде хранит знак. При передаче в метод `toBinaryString` происходит неявное приведение 8-битного байта к 32-битному целому. При этом старшие разряды отрицательного числа "добиваются" установленными битами и `10000001` превращается в `11111111 11111111 11111111 10000001`. Что искажает ожидаемый нами результат. Нам надо как-то обнулить старшие биты. Бинарное представление `0xFF` - это `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`. Применяя операцию [побитового И](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B5_.C2.AB.D0.98.C2.BB_.28AND.29), мы обнуляем биты старших разрядов и получаем требуемое нам `00000000 00000000 00000000 10000001`.

Далее метод `Integer.toBinaryString()` превращает переденное ему целое числов в строку содержащую нули и единицы. Ведущие нули он отбрасывает. С одной стороны, благодаря этому мы получаем интересующее нас 8-битное представление, а с другой, `00000001` он превратит в несуразное `1`.

Решить эту проблему нам поможет `String.format()`. Метод `String.format()` в соответствии со спецификтором формата `%8s` выравнивает строку так, чтобы она занимала не менее 8 символов. Беда в том, что для спецификатора строки `s` выравнивание производится пробелами.

Вот для чего нам нужен последний вызов в строке. Метод `.replace(" ", "0")` заменяет пробелы нулями.

Хотя, я бы предпочёл использовать такой метод форматирования:

```
for (byte b : bytes) {
    String binStr = Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF);
    System.out.print(("00000000" + binStr + " ").substring(binStr.length()));
}
```

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev
благодарю Вас за понимание и развернутый ответ.